# Can PostgreSQL's "COPY table FROM file" statement be used in Go?

Tags: postgresql, csv, go

After reading [`github.com/lib/pq`](http://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq) documentation, it is still not clear for me if it is possible to copy data from a CSV file using a simple `COPY <table> FROM <file> CSV HEADER` command.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
func CopyFromCSV(con Con, tableName, fileName string) error {
    _, err := con.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("TRUNCATE %s", tableName))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    stm, err := con.Prepare(fmt.Sprintf("COPY %s FROM '%s' CSV HEADER", tableName, fileName))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer stm.Close()

    _, err = stm.Exec()
    return err
}
```

Where `tableName` is an existing table, and `fileName` the absolute path to an existing csv file.

I'm getting always the following error after the `con.Prepare` call: `pq: unknown response for copy query: 'C'`

Is it possible to do this in Go with a postgres database using the `github.com/lib/pq` driver?

Comment: Try to execute the same command in the psql command line client.

Comment: It works as expected:

`# COPY <table> FROM '/home/path/to/file.csv' CSV HEADER;`
`COPY 1773`

Comment: The `COPY` function isn't fully supported by the `pq` driver: https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/213. It looks like there are issues with using `COPY` while staying compatible with the database/sql API.  You could probably use another driver if you don't need to conform to database/sql.

Comment: Also note that the `COPY … FROM` and `COPY … TO` statements copy from/to files *on the server*. If you want to use files on a client you'd need at minimum to use `COPY…FROM STDIN` (or `COPY…TO STDOUT`) and do file operations yourself (that's what `psql`'s `\copy` command does as well). As mentioned, that doesn't fit into the `database/sql` API so if a driver were to support this I doubt very much it would be via `Prepare` or `Exec`.

Comment: It should work for server-side paths. If it doesn't then the driver's really very incomplete, because COPY with a server-side path is quite simple. Supporting `COPY ... FROM stdin` or `TO stdout` (for client-side files) is considerably more complex though.

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses https://github.com/lib/pq

```
    import (
        "database/sql"
        "fmt"
        "github.com/lib/pq"
    )

func bulkCopyTest() {
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=verify-full",
        host, port, user, password, dbname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    tx, err := db.Begin()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    stmt, err := tx.Prepare(pq.CopyInSchema("schemaName", "DBName", "columnName", "columnName"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //loop through an array of struct filled with data, or read from a file
    for _, row := range loadCsv {
        stmt.Exec(row.value1, row.value2)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    _, err = stmt.Exec()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = stmt.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tx.Commit()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A rough template to execute COPY command can be found here - https://play.golang.org/p/6y5v3IW8kD

The code below should work for you.

```
   func copyTest() {

    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=verify-full",host, port, user, password, dbname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }


    tx, err := db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = tx.Exec("copy metadata.charvalues_temp from 'C:\\yourlocation\\yourfile.csv' with csv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tx.Commit()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```